# Getting an error while setting up yml file in GitHubActions

Tags: github-actions

I am going through a course and I am getting a syntax error on the second last line below (shell: bash). Any ideas?  If I remove that line I get the same error on the next line (run:  npm ci).

```html
name: Build, test, & deploy
on: [push]
jobs:
  build:
    name:  Project build & package
    if: "!contains(github.even.head_commit.message, '[skip-ci]'"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      -name: checkout repo action
      uses: actions/checkout@master
      -name: Setup Node v10.x
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version:10.x
      -name: Cache Node.js packages
      uses: actions/cache@v1
      env:
        cache-name:  cache-node-packages
      with:
         #use `~/npm` for macOS / Linux agents
         #    & '%AppData%/npm-cache' for Windows agents
         path: ~./npm
         key:  ${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache-name }}-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
      -name: Resolve project dependencies with NPM
       shell: bash
       run: npm ci
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problems were spacing and indentation.  I also had a missing paren.

```html
name: Build, test, & deploy
on: [push]
jobs:
  build:
    name:  Project build & package
    if: "!contains(github.even.head_commit.message, '[skip-ci]')"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: checkout repo action
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Setup Node v10.x
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 10.x
      - name: Cache Node.js packages
        uses: actions/cache@v1
        env:
          cache-name:  cache-node-packages
        with:
           #use `~/npm` for macOS / Linux agents
           #    & '%AppData%/npm-cache' for Windows agents
          path: ~./npm
          key:  ${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache-name }}-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
      - name: Resolve project dependencies with NPM
        shell: bash
        run: npm ci
```